# Check Linq Result for value

Tags: c#, linq

How can I check the results of LINQ query for a specific string value?

I have the following linq query:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = searchParamsTable.AsEnumerable()
                                        .Where(r => r.Field<String>("TABLE") == tableNumbers[i].ToString()
                                        && r.Field<String>("FIELD ") == fieldName[i]);
```

I want to see if the result of that query contains a string(passed in form a text box) "wildcardSearchString".

Comment: What do you mean by "the result of that query"? You've got a sequence of *rows* - which column do you want to check for the presence of the string?

Comment: I should of made that more clear. I want to see if my search value is in the any of the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var searchRows = 
        rows.Where(tr => tr.ItemArray
            .Any(ti => ti.ToString().IndexOf("wildcardSearchString", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) > 0))
```

This will go through each of the rows that was returned, and see if "wildcardSearchString" is in the rows item string representation (ignoring case). Here's the problem though, this won't get you wildcard search support, so you'll have to figure that one out yourself. You can try to use Regex, which would require a slight modification:

```
string searchPattern = "some*string".Replace("*", ".*");
var searchRows = 
        rows.Where(tr => tr.ItemArray
            .Any(ti => Regex.IsMatch(ti.ToString(), searchPattern)))
```

Hope that helps. Just be warned that if they decide to try supplying a Regex pattern than this might really mess up whatever they were searching for, so you just need to be careful of input.

Answer (score 1):

try with this code

```
   DataRow[] array = rows.ToArray();

   array.Contains(yourIndex, yourTextBox.Text);
```

Add this extension

```
 public static bool Contains(this DataRow[] dataRows, string value, int index)
   {
     foreach(var row in dataRows)
     {
        if(row[index].ToString().Contains(value))
        {
             return true;
        }
     } 
     return false;
  }
```

Comment: Aghilas, I tried your example but I get the following error, "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>". How can I correct this?

Comment: Thank's Shyju, Larry try with post modified with ToArray()

Comment: cannot convert from 'System.Data.DataRow' to 'System.Linq.ParallelQuery<string>

Comment: System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSource>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 1):

```
Boolean found = false;
foreach(Datarow d in rows)
{
    foreach(object o in d.ItemArray)
    {
        if(o.ToString().Contains("test")
        {
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you mean something like this?

Comment: Anthony, I tried your approach but I get an error that the object does not contain a definition for 'contains'.

Comment: @LarryBargers did u try o.ToString().Contains("test") ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you're aware of the built-in search capabilities of a `DataTable`? You could use its [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) method:

```
DataRow[] rows = searchParamsTable
    .Select("TABLE = 'Table1' AND FIELD like '%wildcardSearchString%'");
```

Linq is OK but not always required :).